# Ordering of factor level in two scatterplots in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I have created a [forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2byj.png) with the following code

While the Monetary and Air Quality facets/panels displays the citations in the order I want (according the factor level), the meta effect facet/panel does not.

I have tried shifting the two geom_point around and found that only the first one display the citations in the factor order, the second one displays it in alphabetical order. I'm not sure why this is. And how I can get both plots in this graph to display the citations in the order I want it.

```
## Data for the forest plot ##
forestdat= data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=9))
# citations
forestdat$cite = c('Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 1)','Current Study 1', 'Tost et al. (2015, Study 2)', 
                   'Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 3)','Current Study 2', 'Heller & Ullrich (2017)','Monetary','Air Quality','Overall' )
citeorder = c('Monetary','Heller & Ullrich (2017)','Air Quality','Overall','Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 1)','Current Study 1', 'Tost et al. (2015, Study 2)', 
              'Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 3)','Current Study 2')
citeorderforplot = citeorder[9:1]
forestdat$cite = ordered(forestdat$cite, levels = citeorderforplot )

# However I change the order of the three meta effect in cite, they always come out alphabetically
# the same for the connection graphs

# effect size 
forestdat$effectsize = c(-0.3,-0.002,0.12,-0.17,-0.016,-0.04,-0.037,-0.066,-0.048)

# lowerci
forestdat$lowerci = c(-0.479,-0.067,-0.001,-0.321,-0.081,-0.128,-0.168,-0.192,-0.126)

# upperci
forestdat$upperci = c(-0.121,0.063,0.241,-0.019,0.049,0.048,0.095,0.06,0.031)

forestdat$weight = c(0.253,0.414,0.333,0.268,0.381,0.351,NA,NA,NA)

# subgroups settings 
forestdat$subgroup = c('Monetary','Monetary','Monetary','Air Quality','Air Quality','Air Quality','Meta Effect','Meta Effect','Meta Effect')
forestdat$subgroup = ordered(forestdat$subgroup,levels=c('Monetary','Air Quality','Meta Effect'))

# Shape of point
forestdat$shapegroup = c('Individual','Individual','Individual','Individual','Individual','Individual','Summary','Summary','Summary')

## ggplot ## ggplot theme
apatheme=theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(),
        legend.position='none')



library(ggplot2)
# forest plot ---------------------------------------------------------

p=ggplot(forestdat, aes(y=cite, x=effectsize, xmin=lowerci, xmax=upperci))+
  #Add data points and color them black
  geom_point(data=subset(forestdat,shapegroup != 'Summary'),color = 'black', shape = 15, 
             aes(size = weight))+  
  #Add 'special' points for the summary estimates, by making them diamond shaped
  geom_point(data=subset(forestdat,shapegroup == 'Summary'), color='black', shape=18, size=4)+
  #add the CI error bars
  geom_errorbarh(height=.25)+
  #Specify the limits of the x-axis and relabel it to something more meaningful
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.6,0.3), name='Discount Rate Difference')+
  #Give y-axis a meaningful label
    #Add a vertical dashed line indicating an effect size of zero, for reference
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color='black', linetype='dashed')+
  ylab("")+
  #Create sub-plots (i.e., facets) based on levels of setting
  #And allow them to have their own unique axes (so authors don't redundantly repeat)
  #Apply my APA theme
  facet_grid(subgroup~., scales= 'free', space='free')+
  scale_size_area() +
  apatheme
p
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code I have 1) created the dataframe a little  differently to avoid a redundant column 2) removed all the shapegroup logic 3) put color and shape inside aes() then ggplot will a vary the color and shape by subgroup 4) added scale_color_manual and scale_shape_manual to specify the color and shape

```
# Data for the forest plot ##
forestdat= data.frame(
# citations
    cite = c('Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 1)','Current Study 1', 'Tost et al. (2015, Study 2)', 
                   'Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 3)','Current Study 2', 'Heller & Ullrich (2017)','Monetary','Air Quality','Overall' )
)
citeorder = c('Monetary', 'Air Quality','Overall', 'Heller & Ullrich (2017)','Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 1)','Current Study 1', 'Tost et al. (2015, Study 2)', 
              'Joshi & Fast (2013, Study 3)','Current Study 2')

citeorderforplot = citeorder[9:1]
forestdat$cite = ordered(forestdat$cite, levels = citeorderforplot )

# However I change the order of the three meta effect in cite, they always come out alphabetically
# the same for the connection graphs

# effect size 
forestdat$effectsize = c(-0.3,-0.002,0.12,-0.17,-0.016,-0.04,-0.037,-0.066,-0.048)

# lowerci
forestdat$lowerci = c(-0.479,-0.067,-0.001,-0.321,-0.081,-0.128,-0.168,-0.192,-0.126)

# upperci
forestdat$upperci = c(-0.121,0.063,0.241,-0.019,0.049,0.048,0.095,0.06,0.031)

forestdat$weight = c(0.253,0.414,0.333,0.268,0.381,0.351,NA,NA,NA)

# subgroups settings 
forestdat$subgroup = c('Monetary','Monetary','Monetary','Air Quality','Air Quality','Air Quality','Meta Effect','Meta Effect','Meta Effect')
forestdat$subgroup = ordered(forestdat$subgroup,levels=c('Monetary','Air Quality','Meta Effect'))

## ggplot ## ggplot theme
apatheme=theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(),
        legend.position='none')



library(ggplot2)
# forest plot ---------------------------------------------------------

p=ggplot(forestdat, aes(y=cite, x=effectsize, xmin=lowerci, xmax=upperci))+
  #Add data points with color and shape varying by sub group
  geom_point(aes(color = subgroup, shape = subgroup, size = weight)) +  
  # add the error bae
  geom_errorbarh(height=.25)+
  #Specify the limits of the x-axis and relabel it to something more meaningful
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.6,0.3), name='Discount Rate Difference')+
  #Give y-axis a meaningful label
  #Add a vertical dashed line indicating an effect size of zero, for reference
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color='black', linetype='dashed')+
  ylab("")+
  #Create sub-plots (i.e., facets) based on levels of setting
  #And allow them to have their own unique axes (so authors don't redundantly repeat)
  #Apply my APA theme
  facet_grid(subgroup~., scales= 'free', space='free')+
  scale_size_area() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18, 19)) +
  apatheme
  p
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This certainly solved my ordering problem. However, the graph does not show points for the meta effects now. This is because size = weight was set in the now single geom_point(), and there are no weights for the meta effects.      I had the shapegroup logic and the two geom_point() for this reason . Any idea how I could both keep the ordering, and enable all the points to show?

Comment: Follow up: I decide to just give the meta effect an arbitrary weight and the code gives me what I want.